# How to export information into one pdf file of separate page by mPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, mpdf

I'm trying to export data to PDF by using mPDF, PHP and MySQL.
For example I want to export 10 student's information to PDF into one file and each student information to each pages in total 10 pages. But my below code generate only same information to every page.

I've tried as below code but only one page shown.

```
    <?      
        $path = (getenv('MPDF_ROOT')) ? getenv('MPDF_ROOT') : __DIR__;
        ob_clean();
        require_once $path . '/vendor/autoload.php';
          // size in mm
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'margin_left' => 25.4,
            'margin_right' => 25.4,
            'margin_top' => 38.1,
            'margin_bottom' => 31.75,
            'margin_header' => 0,
            'format' => 'A4',
            'orientation' => 'P',
            'margin_footer' => 0
        ]);
        $mpdf->SetTitle("info");
        $mpdf->SetAuthor("Jack");
        $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
        $mpdf->SetWatermarkText("");
        $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
         $mpdf->autoPageBreak = true;
        $mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;
        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

      
        
        $html = '
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        </style>
        </head>
        
        <body style="background: transparent url(ppp.jpg) repeat fixed right top; background-color:#ccffff; ">
';
 $number = count(array_filter($_POST['eid']));
        for($ii=0; $ii<$number; $ii++) 
        {      
              
          $query = "SELECT 
                      `name`, `title`            
                    FROM `p` , `x` 
                    WHERE `p`.`id`=`x`.`id` AND `x`.`id`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["eid"][$ii])."'
                      
                    GROUP BY `x`.`id` ";
        
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);            
        
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
              $name= $row['name'];
             $title = $row['title'];
                      }
$html .= '
        <table width="100%" border=1 ellspacing="5" style="border-collapse: collapse; ">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" > 
              Name :
            </td>
            <td align="center" > 
              '.$name.'
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" > 
              Title :
            </td>
            <td align="center" > 
              '.$title.'
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>            
        
         </body>
        </html>
        
        ';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $fname='Report.pdf';

 }
        $mpdf->Output($fname, 'I');
```

I'm sending id from another page

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $cell['id'];?>" name="eid[]"  />
```

I want to add Name and Title in every separate page for unique student. If 10 student, then it should add in a file of 10 pages.

Can anyone give me some idea, please.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$_POST["eid"][$ii]` contains unique value? Try to `echo` query string to confirm. I would suggest changing your query statement. You can actually do it once using MySQL  `IN()` function.

Comment: Thanks  NcXNaV. I've solved my problem. Please see my solution .

Answer (score 0):

I've solve the problem. It was problem of } position, I've used in  and solved the problem like below code.

```
    </body>
        </html>
        
        ';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $fname='Report.pdf';

 }
        $mpdf->Output($fname, 'I');
```

to

```
}
 </body>
        </html>
        
        ';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $fname='Report.pdf';


        $mpdf->Output($fname, 'I');
```